# Resubmitting the binary data into AppStore issue

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

I am stuck at this point. Scenario is like that - 
  I have already uploaded my application in  apple Appstore and reflecting status is "Ready for sale",This is  great. but there is one issue,now i want to update the binary file. How should i go around it? can  anyone help me out ?
Thanking you in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hey this is very Easy Should i help u now??**

Once your app is Ready for Sale, after that if you want to upgrade your Binary, then you have to release your Apps New Version.If previously your version was 1.0 then it should be Now 1.1 or 2.0 then Modify the Code you had written for that app and Compress the binary and click on New Version for the Corresponding app. That's it. If you still face any problem then let me know... I will be happy to Help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to release the currently approved app for sale before you can update it.

You can release it for sale for one hour in only one microscopic country for one hour, or maybe zero countries, then remove it from sale if you don't want it distributed widely before you update it.

Comment: thank u very much for your reply.But i want to know that first i will release it from sale,then after that again ,will i submit the app with new binary file with updated description?.